# JavaScript RegEx to match punctuation NOT part of any HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Okay, I know there's much controversy with matching and parsing HTML within a RegEx, but I was wondering if I could have some help. [Case and Point.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

I need to match any punctuation characters e.g `. , " '` but I don't want to ruin any HTML, so ideally it should occur between a `>` and a `<` - essentially my query isn't so much about parsing HTML, as avoiding it.

I'm going to attempt to replace wrap each instance in a `<span></span>` - but having absolutely no experience in RegEx, I'm not sure I'm able to do it.

I've figured character sets `[\.\,\'\"\?\!]` but I'm not sure how to match character sets that only occur between certain characters. Can anybody help?

Comment: If you need this to work with arbitrary HTML, it'd probably be easier to let the browser parse the HTML, then find all the text nodes and search them for the punctuation characters.

Comment: You can't parse HTML with a regular expression, you just can't. Parse the HTML, extract the text, and then apply your pattern to it - it's a bit more verbose, but it's _way_ more robust and flexible

Comment: @Pointy being a ridiculous amateur in all sorts of parsing and regular expressions, how would I go about finding all the text nodes? As simple as just detecting specific tags' innerHTML within JavaScript or something more complex?

Comment: Do you want to parse the _current document_?

Comment: The native browser DOM API will tell you. You'd basically just go through the whole DOM, node by node, looking for ones whose `nodeType` attribute is equal to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start off, here's a X-browser dom-parser function:

```
var parseXML = (function(w,undefined)
{
    'use strict';
    var parser,ie = false;
    switch (true)
    {
        case w.DOMParser !== undefined:
            parser = new w.DOMParser();
        break;
        case new w.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") !== undefined:
            parser = new w.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            parser.async = false;
            ie = true;
        break;
        default :
            throw new Error('No parser found');
    }
    return function(xmlString)
    {
        if (ie === true)
        {//return DOM
            parser.loadXML(xmlString);
            return parser;
        }
        return parser.parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');
    };
})(this);
//usage:    
var newDom = parseXML(yourString);
var allTags = newDom.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i=0;i<allTags.length;i++)
{
    if (allTags[i].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span')
    {//if all you want to work with are the spans:
        if (allTags[i].hasChildNodes())
        {
            //this span has nodes inside, don't apply regex:
            continue;            
        }         
        allTags[i].innerHTML = allTags[i].innerHTML.replace(/[.,?!'"]+/g,'');
    }
}
```

This should help you on your way. You still have access to the DOM, so whenever you find a string that needs filtering/replacing, you can reference the node using `allTags[i]` and replace the contents.
Note that looping through *all* elements isn't to be recommended, but I didn't really feel like doing all of the work for you ;-). You'll have to check what kind of node you're handling:

```
if (allTags[i].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span')
{//do certain things
}
if (allTags[i].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'html')
{//skip
    continue;
}
```

And that sort of stuff...
Note that this code is *not* tested, but it's a simplified version of my answer to a previous question. The parser-bit should work just fine, in fact [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6cgf/1/) I've set up for that other question, that also shows you how you might want to alter this code to better suite your needs

Comment: Well it's `.textContent` in some browsers, and generally it's the concatenation of the text of all child DOM nodes.

Comment: @Pointy: very true indeed - I just edited my answer to add that the code was untested, but I think the OP can use the parser function to get started, and work out the rest... If he gets stuck along the way, I'm always ready to help, of course

Comment: Thanks for this! Will there be a large performance hit to using this function, obviously we're looping through the whole document.

Comment: @DanielHanly: I can't say for sure. This function is, in itself, written fairly efficiently: it'll only create a parser instance once, regardless of how many times you call the function for example. The time it takes to process depends on the size of the DOM you're parsing really and, as ever when running client side JS, the client's hardware and their browser... But all in all it shouldn't be _too_ slow

Comment: With our software, speed of processing will be a maximum priority. I guess I'll have to do some testing to see if there is a performance hit. Thanks for your code though, it helps!

Comment: @DanielHanly: If you want to do some performance tests, just open your console on any page and loop through all elements using `allE = document.getElementsByTagName('*');` and apply your code to the entire DOM. There's no real way around parsing and traversing the DOM, and that _will_ be the major "bottleneck". Although, the DOM tree, once parsed, is in memory - looping through that just is very fast

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** As Elias pointed out, native JScript doesn't support the lookaheads.  I'll leave this up in case someone else looks for something similar, just be aware.

Here is the regex I got to work, it requires lookaheads and lookbehinds and I'm not familiar enough with Javascript to know if those are supported or not. Either way, here is the regex:

```
(?<=>.*?)[,."'](?=.*<)
```

Breakdown:

```
1. (?<=>.*?)  -->  The match(es) must have ">" followed by any characters
2. [,."']     -->  Matches for the characters:  ,  .  "  '
3. (?=.*<)    -->  The match(es) must have any characters then "<" before it
```

This essentially means it will match any of the characters you want in between a set of `>  <`.

That being said, I would suggest as Point mentioned in the comments to parse the HTML with a tool designed for that, and search through the results with the regex `[,."']`.

Comment: the standard JS regexp doesn't support lookbehinds, this looks like a Perl regexp to me

Comment: I deal mostly with Powershell (.net), so I am not completely familiar with other languages.  I'll leave it up for future visitors though.

Comment: there are [JS objects](http://xregexp.com/) that do support lookbehinds, but they're not native JS. Incidentally: lookahead's _are_ supported, it's the lookbehind's that are not. Silly and rather annoying from time to time, but a callback can fix that quite easily, too

Answer (score 0):

Dan, resurrecting this question because it had a simple solution that wasn't mentioned. (Found your question while doing some research for a [regex bounty quest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174).)

The Dom parser solution was great. With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html, I'd like to add a simple way to do what you wanted with regex in Javascript.

The regex is very simple:

```
<[^>]*>|([.,"'])
```

The left side of the alternation matches complete tags. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures punctuation to Group 1, and we know they are the right punctuation because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

On [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/wK2qJ5), looking at the lower right pane, you can see that only the right punctuation is captured to Group 1.

You said you wanted to embed the punctuation in a `<span>`. This Javascript code will do it.
I've replaced the `<tags>` with `{tags}` to make sure the example displays in the browser.

```
<script>
var subject = 'true ,she said. {tag \" . ,}';
var regex = /{[^}]*}|([.,"'])/g;
replaced = subject.replace(regex, function(m, group1) {
    if (group1 == "" ) return m;
    else return "&lt;span&gt;" + group1 + "&lt;/span&gt;";
});
document.write(replaced);
</script>
```

Here's a [live demo](http://js.do/code/37965)

**Reference**

1. [How to match pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)
2. [How to match a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)